# Why are my menu bar and windows in my monitor going out of the screen edge?

Tags: display, hdmi, menu-bar, resolution, fullscreen

This issue is really driving me nuts for a while.

I have a Mac Book Pro and using a usb C hub with an hdmi port. I am running a HDMI connector to my monitor. Its fairly decent. Acer 27P with 1080 p res and 165Hz refresh rate.

The issue is when I drag any window to the monitor screen and try to maximize it, all edges go out of the screen borders. I tried to play with the resolution settings to no avail. Even the menu bar is hidden at the top and I have to carefully move the mouse around to guess where the menu items are.

Please help me resolve this. I am hoping to make this a normal 2nd screen where all windows and menu bars are within the screen border and dont extend out of it when made full-screen. Please see the image for an idea. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Because you're using HDMI.  Turn off the overscan on your monitor.

Comment: OMG that was it. I changed the aspect ratio on my monitor to 1:1

Comment: Please add as answer and Ill accept.

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate instead since there is an existing Q&A on this issue, linked above.